# The penalty for changing an airline ticket is per leg or per ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, fees-and-charges

I am wondering what happens with my penalty with a ticket were I am almost certain I will need to change the date of one of the middle legs and subsequently changing all the legs which follow, for example:

```
Tokyo - Sydney - San Francisco - New York
```

If I decide to move everything from my `Sydney` leg 1 week forward, will that be considered as 3 different penalties or just 1?

Comment: What airline is this with? It may depend on the airline...

Comment: Thats good to know, I thought it was just 1 policy. Initially the ticket I am looking at is with AA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will depend on which airline you are flying, and possibly what fare you have purchased. Some airline change fees are per ticket, some are per direction, some are per segment, and I'm sure airlines have found still other ways of assessing them.

Most airlines charge a change fee *per ticket per passenger* without regard to the number of segments in the trip. That is, if you have a single reservation for two passengers on a round trip with one connection in each direction (2 segments per passenger per direction), you'd pay two change fees to leave a day later (plus fare difference).

Charging per segment per passenger is a feature I associate with discount carriers such as Allegiant or Vision, but other airlines in that category do not, like Spirit or EasyJet.

Comment: You are right, I just came from an American Airlines office and they charge a penalty "per change", that means each time you make them "work" for your ticket, not per leg. They also told me that normally changing a ticket will result in much more expensive prices, no matter if the same ticket with the same airline is much cheaper online.